# If $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for all measurable $f, g$, then $X, Y$ are independent.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

In Jean Jacod's Probability Essentials Theorem 10.1, the proof for if $f(X), g(Y)$ are independent for all measurable functions $f, g$, then the random variables $X, Y$ are independent chose specifically $f(x) = x$ and $g(y) = y$. From there, I understood that the proof should go like $X^{-1}(f^{-1}(B)) = X^{-1}(B)$ and $Y^{-1}(g^{-1}(B')) = Y^{-1}(B')$
then $P(X^{-1}(B) \cap Y^{-1}(B')) = P(X^{-1}(B))P(Y^{-1}(B'))$ follows. What I don't understand is how can we choose a specific $f$ and $g$? Shouldn't it be some general measurable $f, g$? I guess there is a difference between "If (for all measurable $f, g$), then ..." and "for all measurable $f, g$, ...", but can't figure it out.

**Edit**: To clarify, my question is: shouldn't we have to prove for all measurable $f, g$? We can show it's true for $f(x) = x$ and $g(y) = y$, but don't we need to show that it's true for all other $f, g$ as well? It's like to prove something for all $n \in \mathbb N$ but then just do it for $n = 1$.

Comment: If f(X) and g(Y) are independent for all measurable f,g then in particular they are independent when we choose specific f and g that suit us for the proof.

Comment: So…. why is this a theorem?

Comment: the theorem is incomplete as its also true that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ would be also independent for any chosen measurable functions $f$ and $g$, that is, the complete version of the theorem is with an "if and only if" instead of just a "then"

Comment: Based on your criticism, you are wanting to prove "(for all measurable f)(for all measurable g)( (f(X),g(Y) are independent) implies (X,Y are independent) )".  This is (1) not what is being claimed, which is good because it's (2) not true.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Can you point out the difference between what is being claimed and my version?

Comment: In short, if a universal generalization appears in the antecedent, we don't prove the universal generalization; rather, we assume it's true and then prove the consequent. 
 When we use a universal generalization, we may choose the constant at will.  This is the difference between proving a statement is true and applying a statement we assume is true to the proof of a different statement.

Comment: Even shorter: We can pull $\exists$ out of the antecedent.  We can pull $\forall$ out of the consequent.  If we swap $\exists$ and $\forall$, both meta-statements fail.

Comment: As Brian says, you want to prove "(for all measurable f)(for all measurable g)[ (f(X),g(Y) are independent) implies (X,Y are independent) ]", where I've changed one set of parens to brackets for emphasis. What's actually claimed is "[(for all measurable f)(for all measurable g)( (f(X),g(Y) are independent)] implies (X,Y are independent)". See how the brackets have moved? *That's* the difference.

Comment: Also, asking only slightly facetiously, but what did Protter do to deserve being omitted as an author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of Theorem 10.1 we're talking about here is the claim: $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for all measurable $f$ and $g$.  There is a slight ambiguity in this formulation of the claim, though this ambiguity isn't really present in the original statement of the theorem.

The ambiguity is that we *might* be universally quantifying $f$ and $g$ over the entire "if and only if" statement.  That is, we might be saying that for every measurable $f$ and $g$, it is true that X and Y are independent if and only if $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent, or -- in symbols -- we might mean:
$$\forall f\in\mathcal{M},\forall g\in\mathcal{M}\:\bigl[(X\perp Y)\iff (f(X)\perp g(Y))\bigr]\qquad (1)$$
**OR** we might be universally quantifying $f$ and $g$ within one "side" of the "if and only if" statement.  That is, we might be saying that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if every measurable $f$ and $g$ give $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ independent, or -- in symbols:
$$(X\perp Y)\iff \bigl(\forall f\in\mathcal{M},\forall g\in\mathcal{M}\:[f(X)\perp g(Y)]\bigr)\qquad (2)$$

@BrianMoehring's comment above is pointing out that (1) is not what what we're claiming, in large part because it's false!  Instead, the claim we are making is (2).

Now, if you had to prove (1) (again, quite a challenge given the statement is false), you'd need to establish both directions of the equivalence "$\!\iff\!$" for all possible choices of $f$ and $g$.  Fortunately, we're only proving (2).  To establish the "$\Rightarrow$" direction, you need to start with only $X\perp Y$ and somehow use this to prove that for every choice of $f,g\in\mathcal{M}$, we have $f(X)\perp g(Y)$.  This is the "hard" direction, and it requires some work.  However, to establish the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, all you have to do is observe that $X\perp Y$ is a special case of $f(X)\perp g(Y)$ where we take $f$ and $g$ both equal to the (measurable) identity function.

So, yes, there is a big logical difference between "for all measurable $f$ and $g$, if $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent then $X$ and $Y$ are independent", which is a false statement, and "if $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent for all measurable $f$ and $g$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent" which is a true statement (and easy to prove simply by taking the special case of $f$ and $g$ equal to the identity).